# How to save to context in custom hook on unmount in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-custom-hooks

I have the following simplified custom hook:

```js
function useSpecialState(defaultValue, key) {
  const { stateStore, setStateStore } = useContext(StateStoreContext);

  const [state, setState] = useState(
    stateStore[key] !== undefined ? stateStore[key] : defaultValue
  );

  const stateRef = useRef(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      setStateStore((prevStateStore) => ({
        ...prevStateStore,
        [key]: stateRef.current,
      }));
    };
  }, []);

  return [state, setState];
}
```

The goal would be to save to a context on unmount, however, this code does not work. Putting `state` in the dependency array of the `useEffect` which is responsible for saving to context would not be a good solution, because then it would be saved on every state change, which is grossly unnecessary.

The context:

```js
const StateStoreContext = createContext({
  stateStore: {},
  setStateStore: () => {},
});
```

The parent component:

```
function StateStoreComponent(props) {
  const [stateStore, setStateStore] = useState({});

  return (
    <StateStoreContext.Provider value={{ stateStore, setStateStore }}>
      {props. Children}
    </StateStoreContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are using this hook?
What was the value of `state` when you encountered the bug? Was it a reference?

Comment: We still don't know what values you passed, what you received, and what you were expecting instead. Try to set some breakpoints in your code, or some `console.log`. A live example (CodeSandbox, StackBlitz) might help as well...

Comment: Second useEffect that sets the value of setStateStore doesn't have dependencies

Comment: @Drew-reese posted perfect answer.
I want to add just one thing: you can simplify this `stateStore[key] !== undefined ? stateStore[key] : defaultValue` to `stateStore[key] || defaultValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

The code you have is fine and technically correct, the observed behavior is caused by the `React.StrictMode` component double-mounting components in non-production builds. In other words, the code & logic should behave as you expect in normal production builds you deploy. This is, or should be, all expected behavior.

## Explanation

The code you have is fine and technically correct. The reason it appears that it is not working is because you are rendering the app within the React `StrictMode` component which executes additional behavior in non-production builds. Specifically in this case it's the double-mounting of components as part of React's check for [Ensuring Reusable State](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state) or [Fixing bugs found by re-running Effects](https://react.dev/reference/react/StrictMode#fixing-bugs-found-by-re-running-effects-in-development) if you prefer the current docs.

> Strict Mode can also help find bugs in Effects.
>
> Every Effect has some setup code and may have some cleanup code.
> Normally, React calls setup when the component mounts (is added to the
> screen) and calls cleanup when the component unmounts (is removed from
> the screen). React then calls cleanup and setup again if its
> dependencies changed since the last render.
>
> When Strict Mode is on, React will also run **one extra setup+cleanup
> cycle in development for every Effect**. This may feel surprising, but
> it helps reveal subtle bugs that are hard to catch manually.

Any component rendered within a `React.StrictMode` component and using the custom `useSpecialState` hook will be mounted, unmounted and run the second `useEffect` hook's cleanup function which will update the state in the context, and then mount again the component.

Here's a small demo toggling the mounting of identical components that use the `useSpecialState` hook, where only one of them is mounted within a `React.StrictMode` component. Notice that "Component A" updates the context state each time when it is mounted ***and*** unmounted, while "Component B" updates the context state only when it unmounts.

[image: Edit how-to-save-to-context-in-custom-hook-on-unmount-in-react]

[image]

Steps:

1. App mounts, context render 0
2. Toggle A mounted: observe mount/unmount/mount, state update A, context render 1
3. Toggle B mounted: observe mount, no state update
4. Toggle A unmounted: observe unmount, state update A, context render 2
5. Toggle B unmounted: observe unmount, state update B, context render 3

Sandbox Code:

```
const MyComponent = ({ label }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useSpecialState(0, "count" + label);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Component{label}</h1>
      <div>Count: {count}</div>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount((c) => c + 1)}>
        +
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [mountA, setMountA] = useState(false);
  const [mountB, setMountB] = useState(false);
  return (
    <StateStoreComponent>
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

        <div>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setMountA((mount) => !mount)}>
            {mountA ? "Unmount" : "Mount"} A
          </button>
          <button type="button" onClick={() => setMountB((mount) => !mount)}>
            {mountB ? "Unmount" : "Mount"} B
          </button>
        </div>
        <StrictMode>{mountA && <MyComponent label="A" />}</StrictMode>
        {mountB && <MyComponent label="B" />}
      </div>
    </StateStoreComponent>
  );
}
```

Comment: Dear Drew! It's times like this when it feels good to be a developer when kind people like you take their time to help when you're stuck. Somehow in my original (not simplified) version if I implement it your way it does not even save (I'm sure I messed up something). I'm trying to find out what. Until then I'll leave an upvote. Thanks again for taking the time to help me!

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs Welcome, happy to help. Since there's a bounty and already provided answers, I wouldn't recommend changing the scope of this post. If you still need help with your more specific code then my suggestion would be to create a new post regarding the more specific issue with the more detailed [mcve]. If you create a new post feel free to ping me in a comment here with a link to it and I can take a look when available.

Comment: I still could not find the bug in my code, but of course, I would not change the scope of the post, since you answered my question and put much effort into it. After the bounty is over I'll award it to you. Thanks again for the help :)

Comment: @LaczkóÖrs Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you see that I could inspect live? I don't mind taking a look to see if it's just something trivial. If you do, just share a link in comment here.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your `useSpecialState` hook and It seems to work fine as expected.
From what I understand that you needed to save the last state value in the context when the component un-mounts.
I created a child component that `increment` the counter and another `toggle` button which mounts and un-mounts that `CounterComponent` while persisting the counter value from the last un-mount.

Here is how I tried it. Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/save-prev-state-8f7qy6?file=/src/App.js:0-2027)

```
import React, {
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useContext,
  createContext
} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const StateStoreContext = createContext({
  stateStore: {},
  setStateStore: () => {}
});

function StateStoreComponent(props) {
  const [stateStore, setStateStore] = useState({});

  return (
    <StateStoreContext.Provider value={{ stateStore, setStateStore }}>
      {props.children}
    </StateStoreContext.Provider>
  );
}

function useSpecialState(defaultValue, key) {
  const { stateStore, setStateStore } = useContext(StateStoreContext);

  const [state, setState] = useState(
    stateStore[key] !== undefined ? stateStore[key] : defaultValue
  );

  const stateRef = useRef(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("child state change ---> ");
    stateRef.current = state;
  }, [state]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mount ---> ");
    return () => {
      console.log("un-mount <--- ");
      console.log("prevStateStore ", stateStore);
      console.log("persistState :: ", key , stateRef.current);
      setStateStore((prevStateStore) => ({
        ...prevStateStore,
        [key]: stateRef.current
      }));
    };
  }, []);

  return [state, setState];
}

const CounterComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useSpecialState(0, "counter");

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox Counter: {counter}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter((prev) => prev + 1)}>increment</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useSpecialState(true, "visible");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StateStoreComponent>
        {visible && <CounterComponent />}
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>toggle</button>
      </StateStoreComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```